# How to match exact number of rows for pivot table in laravel many to many relationship?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

I have tables A, B, AB which is a pivot table I have created a respective relationship for them also. 
now when I want to get data which is exact match id's(array) for a pivot table.

```
$idArray = [3,4]


Model_A::whereHas('b', function($q) use ($idArray) {
        $q->whereIn('b.id', $idArray);  
    })
->with(
    [   
        'b' => function($q) use ($idArray) {
            $q->whereIn('b.id', $idArray);
        },
    ]
)
->get();
```

with whereIn it gets even if match one id from the array but I want to match exact id's.

example collection :

```
[
    0 : {
        sample_data,
        B:[
            0:{
                sample_data,
                id:2
            },
            1:{
                sample_data,
                id:3
            },
            2:{
                sample_data,
                id:4
            }

        ]
    },
    1 : {
        sample_data,
        B:[
            0:{
                sample_data,
                id:3
            },
            1:{
                sample_data,
                id:4
            },
            2:{
                sample_data,
                id:5
            }

        ]
    },
    2 : {
        sample_data,
        B:[
            0:{
                sample_data,
                id:3
            },
            1:{
                sample_data,
                id:4
            },
        ]
    },
    3 : {
        sample_data,
        B:[
            0:{
                sample_data,
                id:3
            },
            1:{
                sample_data,
                id:4
            },
        ]
    }

]
```

now i want following result only for `$idArray = [3,4]`.

```
[
    0 : {
        sample_data,
        B:[
            0:{
                sample_data,
                id:3
            },
            1:{
                sample_data,
                id:4
            },
        ]
    },
    1 : {
        sample_data,
        B:[
            0:{
                sample_data,
                id:3
            },
            1:{
                sample_data,
                id:4
            },
        ]
    }

]
```

[image]
In above picture i get data for destinations(pivot table) with $idArray = [1,5] it get data with destinaions 1,5 and 1 also but i just want to get data who have 1,5 both destinations.
not only 1 or only 5 but who have both and not also like 1, 5, 6 etc

Comment: @lagbox i have used these but didn't get what i want exact match of array of id's for pivot table

Comment: i have seen and use also but if i use whereIn in nested query it will generate count on that clause like even if one matches it gets record

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the documentation for querying relationship existence with [the `wherehas` helper function](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence).

With that function you'll only pull from table A if it has a relationship to table B which will get exact ids from table B. Something like this:

```
$idArray = [3,4]

A_Model::whereHas('b', function($query) use ($idArray){
    $query->whereIn('id', $idArray);
})
->with(['B'=>function($q) use ($idArray) {
    $q->whereIn('B.id', $idArray)
}])
->get();
```

Comment: I don't know what you mean by without the count.

Comment: @abetwothree i just want to get A record if pivot have table have only two record with id 3,4 not at least with ur example it just get that record between 3,4 which matches pivot records and withCount we have to pass where clause when if we pass same where clause in whereIn it exact shows same result matches at least one but i want exact match not at least

Comment: @hu7sy I have no idea what you're talking about. Adding whereHas will get you exact results. Have you tried the code?